# react native : How can I write the code style attached as css to react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

How can I write the code style attached as CSS to react native?
I want to know how to fix the following code to standard code for react native

```
    Btn {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid ('pink');
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
      outline: none;
    },

btn2 {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(360deg);
  background-color: rgb(209, 15, 15);
}
```

Comment: use this https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components but know that not every style is supported; look at its react native styling and make sure to test in both iOS and android (mainly iOS)

Comment: u can help me to transfer my style above ?

Comment: The above code might work without having to do any extra work using styles-components library

Comment: its not works..

Comment: show me a snack..

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Btn {
      width: 50;
      height: 50;
      borderWidth: 1;
      borderColor: 'pink',
      borderRadius: 50/2;
      //cursor: pointer; //don't need this as it's mobile platform
     // transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s; //react native does not support css animation
      outline: 'none';
    },

    btn2 {
      transform: [
        { rotate: '360deg' },
        { scale: 1.2},
      ],
      background-color: 'rgba(209, 15, 15, 1)';
    }
});
```

For animation see this - https://reactnative.dev/docs/easing

Comment: so how i make the animation there instead transition ? can u help me ?

Comment: button animation is not supported by default but text and view is so it depends on what kind of animation you want. This is something you'll have to play around with yourself. You can also enclose button in view and try. Run example code from https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations to see how it works first.